# handle filtering result and pagination together

Tags: php, html, forms, pagination, filtering

this is my entire code

```
<?php 
$params=$_POST;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- filter form -->
    <form method="post" >
        <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $params['search'] ; ?>">
        <button type="submit">filter</button>
    </form>
    <!-- Pagination -->
    <form method="post" >
        <button type="submit" name="page" value="1">1</button>
        <button type="submit" name="page" value="2">2</button>
        <button type="submit" name="page" value="3">3</button>
        <button type="submit" name="page" value="4">4</button>
    </form>
<!-- table of result -->
<table>
    <tr>
        some filtered data
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

there are two forms :

1. filter form
2. pagination

I can filter result by search field and it works perfectly .

and as you see here

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $params['search'] ; ?>">
```

search value maintain after click on `filter` button

**But** when I want to navigate to `next page` of filtered results

search value disappears .

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```html
  <!-- Pagination -->
  <form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="search" value="<?php echo $params['search'] ; ?>"> // modified by AlexGriva
      <button type="submit" name="page" value="1">1</button>
      <button type="submit" name="page" value="2">2</button>
      <button type="submit" name="page" value="3">3</button>
      <button type="submit" name="page" value="4">4</button>
  </form>
```

Please tell me again if you have any questions.

Comment: they must be separated forms